# Need help troubleshooting inconsistent CORS policy issue with full-stack app (Angular and NestJS)

Tags: angular, cors, nestjs

I'm at my wits end with trying to figure out why this issue is happening. At times, usually on first requests for a resource, the server will not attach the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, but it typically works if you refresh and try requesting it again. I'd say this error happens 1/10 requests (it feels that way at least).

Luckily, NestJS has CORS functionality built in, so the only configuration I've done is this:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);

app.enableCors({
    origin: [/http:\/\/localhost/, /https?:\/\/([a-z0-9]+[.])*example.com/],
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'PATCH', 'OPTIONS'],
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Accept', 'X-Requested-With'],
    credentials: true,
    preflightContinue: true,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
});

...
```

I've also observed that simply using a less-secure configuration like the one below still results in the same request failures every once in while. This doesn't make sense to me since any origin should be "valid", yet it still fails.

```
app.enableCors({
    origin: true,
    credentials: true,
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS']
});
```

On the Angular side, I've just got a request interceptor that sets the `withCredentials` field to true.

The error as seen from the client side:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://api.example.com/api/blog/posts' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Sometimes though, it also results from the `XMLHttpRequest` object...

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.com/api/home' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

What makes this difficult is that it seems to work most of the time, but results in a failure every once in a while.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How is your Nest API hosted? I recently tackled a similar problem, but it was more a problem of AWS Lambda & API Gateway.

Comment: @Terenoth It's hosted on Cloud Run... but I solved the problem roughly the same day as asking the question. My app needs a Redis instance and I thought I had switched the environment variables, but I hadn't and wasn't really seeing the error / having it fail to serve queries. I suppose while the server was executing endpoints, the failures from the retries would be thrown and that messed up the results. I fixed that, added the CORS configuration, and now it works perfectly!